# Chown-ed windows partition

Tags: dual-boot, windows, permissions, chown

I need some help, if you could have a look.

I have a laptop dualbooting Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04.

I was trying to share some files on my home network, both from my external hard drive, and from my Windows partition, but I couldn't access it due to wrong permissions. I can't find the thread I followed, unfortunately.

I edited /etc/fstab, and added a line both for my external hard drive, and my Windows partition. Then I set the permissions

```
chmod 755 -R /media/enrico/HDD
```

and acquired ownership

```
chown enrico -R /media/enrico/HDD
```

Then I stupidly repeated the process on the Windows partition, so now Windows boots but crashes randomly, does not run any program, and is basically unusable.
I had a look at the properties of the files in that partition, and it seems that another 'unknows user' was added, (I guess my user in ubuntu) who has full permissions and ownership, and my windows user (and windows itself) does not have full permissions on its files.

Any chance of fixing my mistakes?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to boot your windows install disc or burn one from your Ubuntu Partition. (Microsoft provides legitimate ISO downloads from their website) Then boot from that disc and there should be a repair option. Run that and it should fix your issue and your data should be intact.